# Specify the scope in EL when exist multiple attributes with the same name

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, scope, el

How to explicitly specify the scope for the case that you've multiple attributes with the same name in different scopes?

I have two different attributes with the same name in my JSP, but I need to specify the scope.

I have `${admin.userame}`, when admin is different in `requestScope` and `sessionScope`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the variable this way:

```
${requestScope.admin.username}
```

There is a list of [implicit objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij) which can be accessed in a JSP page:

> Finally, there are objects that allow access to the various scoped
>   variables described in Using Scope Objects.
>
> - pageScope: Maps page-scoped variable names to their values
> - requestScope: Maps request-scoped variable names to their values
> - sessionScope: Maps session-scoped variable names to their values
> - applicationScope: Maps application-scoped variable names to their
>     values

Comment: WoWW, I was trying separating. Thank you very much =].